# $f(\partial K)\subset\partial f(K)$ and $f(\operatorname{Int}K)\subset\operatorname{Int}f(K)$ for a well-behaved $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity, compactness, manifolds-with-boundary

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ be a continuously differentiable bijection with nonzero Jacobian.
Let $K\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ be a compact subset.
Then $f(K)$ is compact. Does the boundary of $K$ map into the boundary of $f(K)$ ? Does the interior of $K$ map into the interior of $f(K)$ ? That is, are
$$f(\partial K)\subset\partial f(K)\qquad\mbox{and}\qquad f(\operatorname{Int}K)\subset\operatorname{Int}f(K)$$
true?
I was wondering if $C^1$ condition, bijectivity, and nonzero Jacobian are enough to ensure that these are true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is true. Indeed, we only need $f$ to be a continuous injection.

We first prove that $f(\partial K)\subset \partial f(K)$. If not, there exists $x\in\partial K$ such that $f(x)\notin \partial f(K)$. Hence $f(x)\in \text{Int }f(K)$ or $f(x)\in \text{Int }\left(\mathbb R^2\setminus f(K)\right)$. If $y=f(x)\in \text{Int }f(K)$, then there exists $r>0$ such that $B=B(y,r)\subset f(K)$. Since $f$ is injective, we have $f^{-1}(B)\subset K$. The continuity of $f$ implies that $f^{-1}(B)$ is an open set containing $x$, hence $x\in \text{Int }K$, contradicting to $x\in\partial K$. Similarly, we can handle the case where $f(x)\in \text{Int }\left(\mathbb R^2\setminus f(K)\right)$. If $y=f(x)\in \text{Int }\left(\mathbb R^2\setminus f(K)\right)$, then there is an open ball $B=B(y,r)\subset \text{Int }\left(\mathbb R^2\setminus f(K)\right)$. Since $f$ is continuous and injective, we have $f^{-1}(B)\subset \mathbb R^2\setminus K$, and $f^{-1}(B)$ is an open set containing $x$, hence $x\in\text{Int }\left(\mathbb R^2\setminus K\right)$, contradicting to $x\in\partial K$.

Now, we prove that $f(\operatorname{Int}K)\subset\operatorname{Int}f(K)$. By [invariance of domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain), $f(\operatorname{Int}K)$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R^2$ contained in $f(K)$, hence $f(\operatorname{Int}K)\subset\operatorname{Int}f(K)$.

Note that here we don't need $K$ to be a closed set. In fact, $K$ can be any set. For completeness, we prove that, indeed, we also have $f(\operatorname{Int}K)\supset\operatorname{Int}f(K)$ and $f(\partial K)\supset \partial f(K)$.

Since $f$ is continuous and injective, we know that $f^{-1}(\operatorname{Int}f(K))$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R^2$ contained in $K$, so $f^{-1}(\operatorname{Int}f(K))\subset \operatorname{Int}K$, implying that $\operatorname{Int}f(K)\subset f(\operatorname{Int}K)$.

To prove $\partial f(K)\subset f(\partial K)$, we first prove $f^{-1}(\partial f(K))\subset \partial K$. Since $f(\operatorname{Int}K)\subset\operatorname{Int}f(K)$, we have $f^{-1}(\partial f(K))\cap \operatorname{Int}K=\emptyset$. Using the invariance of domain we can also prove that $f(\operatorname{Int}\left(\mathbb R^2\setminus K\right))\subset\operatorname{Int}\left(\mathbb R^2\setminus f(K)\right)$, hence $f^{-1}(\partial f(K))\cap \operatorname{Int}\left(\mathbb R^2\setminus K\right)=\emptyset$. So, $f^{-1}(\partial f(K))\subset \partial K$. But this time, we cannot conclude that $\partial f(K)\subset f(\partial K)$, because $f^{-1}(\partial f(K))$ could be empty set (I believe that there should be some examples.) If we require $f$ to be surjective, then everything will be OK.

Therefore, we've proved that

> If $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$ is a continuous bijection and $X\subset\mathbb R^2$ is a subset, then
> $$f(\partial X)= \partial f(X),\qquad f(\operatorname{Int}X)=\operatorname{Int}f(X).$$

**Disclaimer:** I'm not very good at geometry or topology. It is very likely that I've made some silly mistakes in proving the reverse inclusion. So, please read the proof with a critical eye. If there is something wrong, let me know, please.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Two comments: 1) I don't think f(x) can be in the interior of $\mathbb{R}^2\backslash f(K)$, so the second case needs not be considered. 2) The inclusions seem to imply equalities.

Comment: @ashpool You're welcome. You're correct in your both comments. They are based on the closedness of $K$. Indeed, my answer didn't use the closedness, so, in my answer $K$ can be any set, in which case we don't have $\partial K\subset K$ and that's why I considered the second case. Also, if $K$ is an arbitrary set, the equality seems not necessarily true, we may need some more conditions. Anyway, they are good if $K$ is closed.

Comment: In your answer, there is the sentence "By invariance of domain, $f(\operatorname{Int}K)$ is an open subset of $f(K)$." Maybe it is better to say that "$f(\operatorname{Int} K)$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ contained in $f(K)$."

Comment: @ashpool Thanks for your nice comment. You’re correct. I’ve made some edits. :)